# Disable possibility to merge a branch into an other branch

Tags: git

Is it possible to disable possibility to merge one branch into another? For example, I have a branch named `develop` and feature branches named `A`, `B` and `C`.

I want to make impossible to merge develop into A, or into B or into C:

```
git checkout A
git merge develop
```

should return an error.

Comment: As you can see from the two answers, the answer is both no and yes. It depends on what you mean by "disable" and "branch" and so on.

Answer (score 3):

With one obvious proviso, yes, you certainly can do this. It's not hard.

The obvious proviso: you can't stop the administrator of a repo doing whatever they want in it. If I clone your repo, it's my clone and I can do what I want in it. But you can vet anything I push.

You do have to implement some precise meaning of "make impossible to merge develop into A, or into B or into C", this looks good enough I'm just going to show the [update hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#update) for it without further comment:

```
#!/bin/bash
# update hook to prevent pushes updating A, B or C including merges from develop
read ref old new <<<$*
case ${ref#refs/heads/} in 
A | B | C ) 
        if [[ `git merge-base develop $ref` != `git merge-base develop $new` ]]
        then { echo cannot merge develop into ${ref#refs/heads/}; exit 1; }
        fi ;;
esac
```

and you're done. No merge of histories, no matter what anybody calls them, that include history from the develop branch, will be accepted to branch `A`.

---

If you want to warn yourself against doing such merges in your own repos, you can check `MERGE_HEAD` in your (edit: `pre-merge-commit` and) `pre-commit` hook and error out.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible in Git. Instead you would manually review suggested changes to your repo and reject those that you don't like (for example, somebody dragged changes from `develop` to branch `A`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's a pity that such a feature doesn't exist, it will require us to be more vigilant during our reviews..

Comment: @MathAng That's not really a sane feature to want. Forbidding certain commits from merging into certain branches doesn't actually prevent *files* from being added to those branches. Even if you could forbid the merge operation you're talking about, it wouldn't actually offer any useful protection. You're not actually stopping the content on `develop` from making its way into `A`.

Comment: Indeed, but this would avoid some errors, although voluntarily we could bypass this operation in the way you say

Thanks a lot, your answers were clear

Comment: You are only referring to gur in your question. Depending on weather you use GitHub, Gitlab or another platform to review your PRs there would be options to support the review process by automation.